# When Should I Be Closing My DB Connection In My Class

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have the following class that handles most of my database queries, prepared statements,etc. Below is just a sample of the class I have.

PhP (database.php)

```
class Database{

 public $mysqli;


  function __construct(){
    // Open the connection to the DB on construct
    $this->open_connection();
  }

  private function open_connection(){
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
      die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " ( " . mysqli_connect_errno()  . " ) ");
    }
  }

  /*
  * Creates a user
  */
  public function create_user($username, $password){
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Users(username,password,dateCreated) VALUES(?,?,NOW())");
    $password = $this->hash_password($password);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    if( !$stmt->execute() ) :
      $error =  "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    endif;
    $stmt->close();
    return $error;
  }

  // ....
}
$db = new Database();
```

Because I am instantiating that class every time on page load when I am requiring that file, how should I go about closing my connection to the database? Can I just leave it open?

Answer (score -1):

You can leave it open because the connection will be closed whenever your script finishes execution anyway. The [PHP website on mysqli_close](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php) provides the following information on why it's recommended to close the connection anyway:

> Open non-persistent MySQL connections and result sets are
>   automatically destroyed when a PHP script finishes its execution. So,
>   while explicitly closing open connections and freeing result sets is
>   optional, doing so is recommended. This will immediately return
>   resources to PHP and MySQL, which can improve performance. For related
>   information, see [freeing resources](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php#language.types.resource.self-destruct)

Comment: I agree with you as I said that it's recommended to close the connection anyway. :)

Answer (score -1):

Always: Close all resources you don't need anymore as soon as possible. You can't leave it open until your next page is requested because it terminates anyway as soon as your server finished serving a particular page.

When browsing to another page, you will have to open the connection again anyway. That's where connection pooling comes in handy: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqlnd-mux.connection_pool.html